# Column data missing when i import data from .csv excel to grid view in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, gridview

I am trying to export my excel sheet data to my grid view in ASP.NET site. Grid view is populating the data but is missing the excel sheet column data `EMP_CODE`.

**Excel Data**:

[image]

**Rendered GridView**:

[image]`

**Code for populating `asp:GridView`**:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.FileName != "")
    {
        try
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Appraisal/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
            CvsPath = null;
            string constr = null;
            //constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connStr").ToString;
            constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection dwConn = new SqlConnection(constr);
            //con.Open()
            CvsPath = Server.MapPath("~/Appraisal/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
            //Response.Write(CvsPath)
            FileUpload1.Dispose();
            // Dim constr As String
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection csvConn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            //constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connStr").ToString
            //csvConn.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;;Data Source=" + CvsPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"");
            csvConn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + CvsPath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
            //
            csvConn.Open();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand csvCmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            csvCmd.CommandText = ("Select * From [Sheet1$]");
            //csv file being in localDir
            //assign the cmd to a connection
            csvCmd.Connection = csvConn;
            //create csv reader
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader csvRdr = null;
            //insert the csv contents into a reader
            csvRdr = csvCmd.ExecuteReader();
            //open sql connection
            dwConn.Open();
            //create sqlbulk copy to insert the csv reader into db table
            SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(dwConn);
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[MstAppointmentRegister]";
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(csvRdr);
            //close csv connection
            csvRdr.Close();
            csvConn.Close();
            //close sql connection
            dwConn.Close();
            lblError.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";

            if (lblError.Text == "File Uploaded Successfully")
            {
                FillGridFromExcelSheet();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<br />" + ex.Message);
        }
        //Response.Redirect("upload_ClosingPrice.aspx?act=1");
    }
    else
    {
        lblError.Visible = true;
        lblError.Text = "Please Select File";
    }
}
```

**`GridView` and `SqlDataSource` markup**:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="ExcelGridView" runat="server" 
        Cssclass="table table-striped" 
        Visible="False" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="SRID" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
        OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" 
        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" HeaderText="Modify" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" HeaderText="Remove" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SRID" HeaderText="SRID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Emp_Code" HeaderText="Emp_Code" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Letter" HeaderText="Letter" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Letter" HeaderText="Letter" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="First_Name" HeaderText="First_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address_Line1" HeaderText="Address_Line1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address_Line2" HeaderText="Address_Line2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address_Line3" HeaderText="Address_Line3" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOJ" HeaderText="DOJ" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CTC" HeaderText="CTC" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CTC_in_Words" HeaderText="CTC in Words" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Data Source=103.21.58.193;Initial Catalog=jig_match_db;User ID=jig_match_db;Password=atheros@7412" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [MstAppointmentRegister] WHERE [SRID] = @SRID"  
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [MstAppointmentRegister]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [MstAppointmentRegister] SET [Name] = @Name, [First_Name] = @First_Name, [Address_Line_1] = @Address_Line_1, [Address_Line_2] = @Address_Line_2, [Address_Line_3] = @Address_Line_3, [DOJ] = @DOJ, [Designation] = @Designation, [CTC] = @CTC, [CTC_in_Words] = @CTC_in_Word WHERE [SRID] = @SRID" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [MstAppointmentRegister] ([Name],[First_Name],[Address_Line_1],[Address_Line_2],[Address_Line_3],[DOJ],[Designation],[CTC],[CTC_in_Words]) VALUES (@Name,@First_Name,@Address_Line_1,@Address_Line_2,@Address_Line_3,@DOJ,@Designation,@CTC,@CTC_in_Words)">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="SRID" Type="Int64" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Emp_Code" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Letter" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="First_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address_Line1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address_Line2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address_Line3" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DOJ" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Designation" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CTC" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CTC_in_Words" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Database schema for the table `MstAppointmentRegister`**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MstAppointmentRegister](
    [SRID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EMP_Code] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [Letter][varchar](200) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [First_Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Address_Line_1] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Address_Line_2] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [Address_Line_3] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [DOJ] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Designation] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [CTC] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [CTC_in_Words] [varchar](150) NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_mstappointmentregister] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SRID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Please help me out ?

Comment: please show the structure of the database table `MstAppointmentRegister` also chec k if`Emp_Code` is inserted into the database.

Comment: Emp code is not getting inserted :(

Comment: so the problem is with BulkInsert. Check if there is a Emp_Code column in your database. Whats it data type? Also check for any spelling errors for the column name in table and excel

Comment: Hi naveen , my database structure is as follows :

Comment: The problem is that while using SqlBulkCopy, the Emp_Code is not filled to the database. Right?

Comment: Yes the problem is with the EMp_code and I cant figure it out why ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117781/discussion-between-jatin-and-naveen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SqlBulkCopy` the column mappings are case-sensitive regardless of the case sensitivity setting in target DB.

As MSDN notes,

> Column mappings define the mapping between data source and the target
>   table.
>
> If mappings are not defined—that is, the ColumnMappings
>   collection is empty—the columns are mapped implicitly based on ordinal
>   position. For this to work, source and target schemas must match. If
>   they do not, an InvalidOperationException will be thrown.
>
> If the ColumnMappings collection is not empty, not every column present in
>   the data source has to be specified. Those not mapped by the
>   collection are ignored.

In your case the excel returns the column `Emp_Code` and the table in the database has the column `EMP_Code`. The mapping fails as **`Emp_Code != EMP_Code`**.

MSDN Link: [SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping(v=vs.90).aspx)